# MIcrophone headset: not working but found

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, audio-jack

I have my headset  connected with a *male* stereo jack adapter. My ubuntu recognizes my headset which correctly reproduces sounds i.e. in *Settings/Sounds* I can choose between internal and headset microphone.

However the microphone (which is found even by `pavucontrol`) doesn't work. I have tried rising the volume with `alsamixer` but nothing changes.

My headset is: Trust Reno headset.

My ubuntu is 20.04.

Any idea?

Comment: What make and model of headset?  Please edit and add to question.

Comment: @David I have done an edit.

Comment: @David I think an usb adapter should help.

Comment: @David before using a male jack adapter my headset was not found. Now when I plug it in my laptop I have to choose (in a window) the headset or the headphones.

Comment: @David as I wrote at the beginning of the question, it is a male adapter just like [this](https://www.reichelt.com/headset-adapter-3-5-mm-klinkenbuchse-auf-2x-stecker-0-12-m-delock-65459-p162429.html?CCOUNTRY=445&LANGUAGE=de&PROVID=2814&gclid=Cj0KCQjwvYSEBhDjARIsAJMn0lh1D-vtrL6ZL08PoKa81zccVkox7gQWR_TDH1dgR9v3QvImyHo5jrgaAvIbEALw_wcB&&r=1)

Comment: I can see how that adapter would confuse the software it may not know how to separate the 2 channels.

Comment: @David I have to choose the channel "headphones" (that cable with the headphones symbol). In that way the sound works. On the other hand if I choose the other channel/cable the microphone doesn't work that way either. Maybe a usb adapter should help coping with that.

Comment: Have you tried only plugging it into the mic jack?

Comment: @David as I wrote in the prev comment when I plug it into the other channel/cable it doesn't work. In addition even the headphones stop working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a USB-jack adapter makes things easier. In this way you can have both headphones and microphone activated. It should be instantly detected by the system.